# How to make button clickable in React App?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a music player, and for playing the songs I have created the buttons but on UI the buttons are not responding. I have literally tried everything but nothing works.

```
export class CreateSong extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const url = window.location.href;
        this.id = url.split('/')[4];
        this.audioEl = createRef(null);
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.currentIndex = parseInt(this.id) - 1;
        this.nextIndex = 0;
        this.prevIndex = 0;
        this.state={
            song: {},
            allSongs: [],
            imagePath: variables.IMAGE_URL
        }
        this.nextSong = (<h6> </h6>)
        this.prevSongNav = (<button className='btn skip-btn'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBackward} /></button>)
        this.nextSongNav = (<button className="btn skip-btn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faForward} /></button>)
        this.togglePlayPause = () => {
            const prevValue = this.isPlaying;
            this.isPlaying = !prevValue;
            if (!prevValue) {
                this.audioEl.current.play();
            } else {
                this.audioEl.current.pause();
            }
        }
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'songs')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({allSongs: data});
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });

        fetch(variables.API_URL+'songs/'+this.id)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>{
            this.setState({song: res});
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    render(){
        const{
            song,
            allSongs,
            imagePath
        } = this.state;

        if (allSongs.length > 0){
            if (this.currentIndex + 1 > allSongs.length - 1){
                this.nextIndex = 0
            }
            else{
                this.nextIndex = this.currentIndex + 1;
            }
            if (this.currentIndex - 1 < 0){
                this.prevIndex = allSongs.length - 1
            }
            else{
                this.prevIndex = this.currentIndex - 1;
            }
            this.nextSong = (<h6>Next up: {allSongs[this.nextIndex].name} by {allSongs[this.nextIndex].artist}</h6>)
            this.prevSongNav = (<button className='btn skip-btn'><Link to={'/songs/' + allSongs[this.prevIndex].song_id}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBackward} /></Link></button>)
            this.nextSongNav = (<button className="btn skip-btn"><Link to={'/songs/' + allSongs[this.nextIndex].song_id}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faForward} /></Link></button>)
        }

        console.log(this.isPlaying);
        return(
            <div className="cont">
                <div className="music-player container">
                    <div className="cover">
                        <img alt="..." src={imagePath + song.image} className="songImg" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="title">
                        <h1>{song.name}</h1>
                        <h3>{song.artist}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <audio src={imagePath + song.song} ref={this.audioEl}></audio>
                    <div className="music_ctrl">
                        {this.prevSongNav}
                        <button className="btn play-btn" onClick={this.togglePlayPause}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={this.isPlaying ? faPause : faPlay} /></button>
                        {this.nextSongNav}
                    </div>
                    <div className='nextSong'>
                        {this.nextSong}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the code, can someone please suggest anything how to resolve this? I tried in functional component first but there also the button was not working. So, I implemented my code in class component hoping that the button will work, but still the same issue. It's like the button is disabled because simple click is also not happening, but state is enabled for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move this.togglePlayPause method outside constructor ?
in the same level as Lifecycle method componentDidMount